# PHP orders with account id display each order separately from the database

Tags: php

Hey any help is appreciated here as I've got a mega headache from this. To begin, I've just setup an orders table which looks like this:

[image]

Anyway, in the database the column"user_id" is used to uniquely identify each users separate orders. 
But with more than one order I can't figure out how to display each separate order to each user.        This is my current configuration for collecting items from the database (it's bare and not configured correctly as I've tried so many options at this point my ctrl and z keys respectively have turned to ash. Please can someone guide me with this I'm clueless.

```
$sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM payments WHERE user_id =:user_id";
$statement = $database->prepare($sqlquery);
$statement->execute(array(':user_id' => $id));

while($rs = $statement->fetch()){
  $payer_email[] = $rs["payer_email"];
  $payer_name[] = $rs["payer_name"];
  $item_price[] = $rs["item_price"];
  $item_currency = $rs["item_currency"];
  $item_number = $rs["item_number"];
  $payment_status = $rs["payment_status"];
  $user_id = $rs["user_id"];
  $payment_id = $rs["payment_id"];

}

 ?>
```

Comment: Instead of using a while loop I could have just created a separate variable which is assigned to the PDO fetchAll method, then use a foreach loop to  cycle through the array.